# Partial re-colorizing a Bitmap at runtime

Tags: actionscript

I'm drawing some cars. They're Bitmap's, loaded from PNG's in the library. I need to be able to color the cars-- red ones and green ones and blue ones, whatever. However, when you paint the car green, the tires should stay black, and the windows stay window-color.

I know of two ways to handle this, neither one of which makes me happy. First, I could have two bitmaps for each car; one underneath for the body color, and one on top for detail bits. The underneath bitmap gets its transform.colorTransform set to turn the white car-body into whatever color I need. Not great, because I end up with twice as many Bitmap's running around on screen at runtime.

Second, I could programmatically search-and-replace "white" with "car-body" color when I load the bitmap for each car. Not great either, because the amount of memory I take up multiplies by however many colors I need.

What I would LIKE would be a way to say "draw this Bitmap with JUST THE WHITE PARTS turned into this other color" at runtime. Is there anything like this available? I will be less than surprised if the answer is "no," but I figure it's worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have answered the question yourself.

I think your first approach would need only two transparent images: one with pixels of the parts that need to change colour, one with the rest of the image. You will use colorTransform or ColorMatrix filter by case. It might even work with having the pixels the need  the colour change covered with Sprite with a flat colour set on overlay ?
The downside would be that you will need to create a 'colour map'/set of pixels to replace for each different item that will need colour replacement.

For the second approach:
You might isolate the areas using something like [threshold()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#threshold%28%29).

For speed, you might want either to store the indices of the pixels you need to replace in an Vector.<int> object that could be used in conjuction with BitmapData's [getVector()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#getVector%28%29) method. (You would loop once to fetch the pixel indices that need to be replaced)

Since you will use the same image(same dimensions) to fill the same content with a different colour, you'll always loop through the same pixels. Also keep in mind that you will gain a bit of speed by using [lock()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#lock%28%29) before your loop to setPixel() and [unlock()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#unlock%28%29) after the loop.

Alternatively you could use [Pixel Bender](http://kafkaris.com/blog/2010/09/02/pixel-bender-background-subtraction/) and try some green screen/background subtraction techniques. It should be fast and wouldn't delay the execution of the rest of your as3 code as Pixel Bender code runs in it's own thread.

Also check out [Lee's Pixel Bender](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/webcam-green-screen-effect-w-pixel-bender/) subtraction technique too.

Although it's a bit old now, you can use some knowledge from @Quasimondo's [article](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000615.php) too.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused where you see the difference between your second approach and the one you would like to have. You can go over your loaded bitmap pixel by pixel and read out the color. If it turns out to be white replace it with another color. I do not see occurence of multiplied memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try my selective color transform: http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000614.php - it's from 2006, so some parts of it could probably be replaced by a pixel bender filter now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just load the pieces separately, perform the color transform on the one you want to change, then do a BitmapData.copyPixels() with the result? The blit routine runs in machine code, so is wicked fast. Doing it pixel by pixel in ActionScript would be glacially slow in comparison.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()